# .NET Core 3.1 - SQL Server - create a new login and user - issue with the parameters

Tags: .net, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a new login and user with the `SqlCommand` class. But, I cannot use the parameters:

```
await using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
await connection.OpenAsync();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("create login @login with password = '@pwd';", connection);

command.Parameters.Add(createParam("@login", "some_login"));
command.Parameters.Add(createParam("@pwd", "rsmZYdX187_V_xu1!@99"));

int results = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();


private SqlParameter createParam(string name, string value)
{
    var parameter = new SqlParameter
    {
        DbType = DbType.String, 
        SqlValue = value,
        ParameterName = name
    };

    return parameter;
}
```

but I'm still getting the error message **Incorrect syntax near '@login'.** I also tried to remove `@` from the name. Without using the parameters and putting the values inside the query it works fine, but that's now I want (and also it proves the syntax is fine). So, what's wrong here ?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're setting the [SqlValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter_SqlValue) property, rather than than [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value?view=netframework-4.8) property. I've never noticed the `SqlValue` property before, but I found the error message you posted to be somewhat suspicious as the `@login` parameter doesn't seem to be getting replaced.

Try this instead:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter
{
    DbType = DbType.String, 
    Value = value,
    ParameterName = name
};
```